# GSA not searching sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, google-search-appliance

We have a GSA which currently crawls our old site http://www.site.co.uk/site

However we have created a new site called https://new.site.co.uk which is on a diffent server.

In our htaccess file on the old server we have directed all traffic from old site to new site as we want to use the site on the subdomain as our new site until we have migrated all the content off the old one.

We have also pointed all links to the old site to site.co.uk/site as this is where the old CMS files live.

So, I have created a new collection on the GSA and also added new site to the content sources.

However when I look at the diagnostics the GSA can see the top lever folders on the new site but has an error next to / saying "Retrying URL: Connection reset by peer during fetch"

I have added the hostname and IP to the DNS overrides on the GSA too.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: If you use Real Time Diagnostics on the GSA admin console to request a couple of URLs from your new site what do you see?

What you have described sounds like a connectivity issue.

Comment: Connection reset by peer can also mean that the server is loverloaded and not able to serve up the pages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be connection issue. Could you test to new domain on Network Diagnostics(URLs To Test).